# DELPHI XE8 : No refresh for TRectangle on Android during OnCreate event

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I created this function on DELPHI XE5, it's work very well.
You create a single image with all your icons, you load this image in a TBitmap (IDE in my exemple), and you create a lot of small TRECTANGLE in the form.

During the onCreate, i call Mapping method to set the background of each Trectangle.

**BUT IN DELPHI XE8, It's not working on ANDROID**

This is the mapping function.

```
Procedure TForm1.Mapping(Const Obj:TRectangle;Const ofx,ofy:Integer);
Var
  Arect    : TRectF;
  FBitmap  : TBitmap;
Begin
  Arect:=TRectF.Create(0,0,Obj.Width,Obj.Height);
  Obj.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.None;
  Obj.Fill.Kind   := TBrushKind.Bitmap;
  Obj.Fill.Bitmap.WrapMode := TWrapMode.TileOriginal;
 //Create Crop Bitmap
  FBitmap:=TBitmap.create( Round(Obj.Width), Round(Obj.Height)) ;
   Try
    FBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene();
    FBitmap.Canvas.ClearRect(ARect,StringToAlphaColor('$00000000'));
    FBitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(IDE,
                        TRectF.Create(ofx,ofy,ofx+Obj.Width,ofy+Obj.Height),
                                Arect, 100) ;
    FBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    //Assign  Crop  image to Rectangle object 
    Obj.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.Assign(FBitmap);

   Finally
    FBitmap.Free;
   End;
End;
```

The picture (delphiXE.png) is deploying in "asset/internal", and opening in oncreate.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var  Mfile:String;
begin
  IDE := TBitmap.Create(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
 {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Mfile:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'delphiXE.png');
 {$ELSE}
  Mfile:=TPath.Combine(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), 'delphiXE.png');
 {$ENDIF}
  If FileExists(MFile)
  Then begin
       IDE.LoadFromFile(MFile);
       Mapping(Logo,0,0);
       End
  Else ShowMessage('NO '+MFile);
end;
```

In Windows, everythings works fine, but no in Android, but if i add a simple onclick event with Mapping(Logo,0,0); call, the mapping work, but i need to click first on the grey Trectangle to set it background

Any idea ?

**UPDATED :**
Using a Timer, the mapping function is working and the trectangle have the good picture, but if i switch to another application and go back to my application, the picture disappear and the Trectangle turn back to solid gray.

That mean that the internal paint of the TRectangle is not updated. Why ?

Comment: How is it "not working"? Does it show something unexpected? Does it show nothing? Does it give you an error? Does it fail to compile?

Comment: Did it work on Android with XE5?

Comment: @David According to the question, that would be Yes.

Comment: In the form, the trectangle is filled by solid color (gray), normaly when the application init, the fill parameter change to bitmap, and the mapping function create  the bitmap needed.

Comment: Its working in Android with XE5, windows XE5, Windows XE8, but not on Android with XE8 (maybe also in XE7).  I can post my TEST PROJECT

Comment: Basically in XE7 and XE8 the surface has to be initialized first on Android. Which means you could set a TTimer to 1 second or so and call you mapping function from there. It sounds like you said it works if you apply it in an OnClick event. I have encountered something similar in XE7 and I think that was one workaround. Might also try the OnIdle event. I'm not sure it is a bug just a change on how or when a surface can be accessed (or is initialized). Blocking code in OnCreate is generally bad as it slows your app loading time.

Comment: @FMXExpress : Thank's, using a timer,it's is working. where can i find information about  surface initialization on XE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for you help, i find a solution and the origin of the problem.

The fact that the picture in the Trectangle was not persistent help me.

```
//Assign  Crop  image to Rectangle objects 
Obj.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.Assign(FBitmap);
```

is no longer working like it worked on DELPHI XE5 on Android. It 's copy the bitmap but not on a persistent way. This is why it's working with onclick, but disappear when i switch application.

So, I changed this line by

```
// Force the size of TRectangle internal Bitmap
Obj.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.SetSize(FBitmap.Width,FBitmap.Height);
// Copy the crop bitmap in TRectangle Internal Bitmap
Obj.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.CopyFromBitmap(FBitmap);
```

and in my TEST PROJECT, it's working.

I hope this can help another developper.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to test the return of Canvas.BeginScene ? If it's fail, that mean that the graphic context system does not succeded to init. (yes, that work on XE5 and perhaps other, go figure, they perhaps change the init sequence somewhere)
In Creation phase, certainly not abnormal. 
you should do this somewhere else.

Comment: I uses BeginScene in the temporal bitmap (for croping) and the result it's always true.. Thanks for you idea.